# addthis floating vertical bar showing horizontally in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, addthis

Addthis floating vertical bar not working properly in a wordpress content-single page!

Here is my code

```
    <div class="addthis_bar addthis_bar_vertical addthis_bar_large" style="top:50px;left:50px;">
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style">
    <span><a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="box_count"></a></span>
    <span><a class="addthis_button_tweet" tw:count="vertical"></a></span>
    <span><a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" g:plusone:size="tall"></a></span>
    <span><a class="addthis_button_stumbleupon_badge" su:badge:style="5" ></a></span> 
    <span><a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit"  pi:pinit:url="<?php echo get_permalink(get_the_ID()); ?>" pi:pinit:media="<?php echo $thumb_image[0];?>" pi:pinit:layout="vertical"></a></span>
    <span><a class="addthis_counter"></a></span>
</div>
```

I have followed the instructions in [addthis site](http://www.addthis.com/labs/floating-vertical-bar).

I have tried with other addthis tool boxes [32 X 32 medium sized icons], but end up with error.

The below code is the other addthis code which i have tried,

```
<div class="addthis_bar addthis_bar_vertical addthis_bar_medium" style="top:50px;left:50px;">
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style">
    <span><a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a></span>
    <span><a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a></span>
    <span><a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a></span>
    <span><a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a></span>
    <span><a class="addthis_button_compact"></a></span>
</div>
```

I haven't used any seperate styles (CSS) for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: this question would be better off at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ the question is also vague, what have you tried? what's the CSS?

Comment: Thanks janw for your response. I have not used any seperate styles (css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue that's been reported to AddThis support.  I too am using the AddThis CSS style, addthis_bar_vertical, to display my AddThis toolbar in a vertical style that floats on the side of the browser window, and it has been working fine for the past several months.

But, as of a couple of days ago, the toolbar is now showing horizontally at the bottom of my browser window.

I'm waiting for AddThis to resolve the issue, but feel free to report this issue to their Support to add your voice to this annoying issue!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Mari for your suggestion. I reported this issue to addthis. [Here is the solution](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/questions/359679-addthis-floating-vertical-bar-showing-horizontally-in-wordpress)

Addthis team recently updated the vertical sharing bar

So [here](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/questions/359679-addthis-floating-vertical-bar-showing-horizontally-in-wordpress) is the latest code and its working fine..